# how to open a port entered by user java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, port

I have two doubts

**FIRST**.

I am creating a desktop application in netbeans, I want to **open** **a** **port** **entered by user**.I have created **two files** in same package, **getting** port **number** from user its in **one file** and **processing** on it is **second** file.

I have **created** **object** of that class for getting user's entered port number its **not showing any error** but **port is not opening** on that number i have checked **using tcp view**

here is code of first file

**Server.java**

```
 package server;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Server extends Thread {
      public static int SERVERPORT;
      private boolean running = false;
      public volatile boolean stop = false;
      public Socket client = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainFrame frame = new mainFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        SERVERPORT = frame.portnum;//here i am getting port number from 2nd file
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        running = true;
        try {
            System.out.println("Server Has Started........ \n Waiting for client........");
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            try {
                while (!stop && running) {
                    client = serverSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println("Connection Accepted......");
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                    String usercmnd = in.readLine();
                    if (usercmnd != null) {
                        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                        Process p = runtime.exec(usercmnd);
                    }
                }
```

here is 2nd file where user have to enter a port number

**mainFrame.java**

```
package server;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.net.*;
//import server.Server;


/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class mainFrame extends JFrame {
private Server  mServer;
public int portnum;
   public mainFrame() {
        super("mainFrame");
        mServer = new Server();
        initComponents();
        setIcon();labInfo.setText("Not Connected");
        try{ ipAdd.setText(String.valueOf(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()));
        }catch(Exception e){labInfo.setText(e.getMessage());}

    }


    private void connActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        if(port.getText().equals(""))
        {
           labInfo.setText("Port number cannot be empty!!");
        }else{
            portnum=Integer.parseInt(port.getText());//here i am getting user's entered port number
            conn.setEnabled(false);port.setEditable(false);
            labInfo.setText("Waiting for Connection.....");
            mServer.start();
        }
    }                                    

    private void disconnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        mServer.requestStop();
        labInfo.setText("Not Connected");
        port.setEditable(true);
        conn.setEnabled(true);        
    }
```

**SECOND**.

Is there any way to check entered port number is currently using so then we can alert the user to use another port number...???

Comment: Sorry, this sounds like a terrible idea.  It doesn't seem secure to allow a user to open any port they wish.  I'd redesign if I were you.

Comment: I think you have a misconception about how GUI works. When you display the window, you don't have the value in any field yet. You only have the value when a change event is dispatched to that field. So at the line `SERVERPORT = frame.portnum` you don't have any value in `SERVERPORT`, because there is nothing that sets `portnum` to any value.

Comment: @RealSkeptic so what i have to do? actually i am creating server client communication in that user can start server with specified port number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather suggest you run the `mainFrame` class first from which you can call the `Server` class at the click of the `Button` to retrieve the port number entered in the `TextField`. I can't seem to help with the full code but you can change your `connActionPerformed()` method to

```
   private void connActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        boolean success = false;
        do {
            try {
                if (port.getText().equals("")) {
                    labInfo.setText("Port number cannot be empty!!");
                } else {
                    portnum = Integer.parseInt(port.getText());//here i am getting user's entered port number
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portnum);
                    System.out.println("Connected to Server");
                    mServer = new Server(serverSocket);//Which means you need to implement a constructor with a Server argument.

                    //conn.setEnabled(false);
                    //port.setEditable(false);
                    //abInfo.setText("Waiting for Connection.....");
                    mServer.start();
                    success = true;
                }

            } catch (BindException ex) {
                System.out.println("Port in use");
            }
        } while (success);

    }
```

And then you can implement a constructor like this:

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public Server(ServerSocket serverSoket){
        this.serverSocket = serverSoket;
    }
```

**NOTE**: since this code is not complete, manipulate to suit your needs.
Hope this would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: yes its open a port entered by user but on **console** i am contineous getting **port in use** and then i can not use the application except close that task in task manager....

Comment: yes its working finally, just **interchanging** the value of **success**